# How do you compute the determinant of the square matrix with $1$'s on the diagonal and the entry's next to it?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do you compute the determinant of the square matrix with $1$'s on the diagonal and the entry's next to it (in other words, the entry in the $i$-th row and the $j$-th column equals $1$ if $|i-j|\leq1$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Determinant).

Answer (score 0):

Use induction over the dimension of the matrix. In the induction step evaluate the determinant. You will get subdeterminants inside that are of the same form